# I want list the subcategory column in checkbox based on category table

Tags: php, mysql

[image]
I want to show the subcategory column has in checkbox  which belongs to ch_cat table.

Here I have listed my category table:

```
    <form action="tutorsubject.php">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ch_cat`";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){ ?>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="segment[]" value="<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['p_cat']; ?>
            </label>
            <?php    
            }
            ?>
        <input type="submit" value="tutorsubject"/>
        </form>
```

**Tutorsubject.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['tutorsubject'])) {
    $segment = $_POST['segment'];
    print_r($segment);
    //how to write query here based on child_cat table.
}
```

**my questions are:**

1. First I have listed child_cat column has in checkbox. Here user select the teaching segment.(assume I selected Btech,java,or number
   of choice made by user.)
2. Now print_r gives.`Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 13 )`.Here 3 and 13 is the
   child_cat primary key passing to sub_cat table.
3. How write query based on print_r values .**IN my image you can see 3
   and 13 has sub_cat column values**.how to bring in query.
4. I am facing problem in  how write to the query.the values which we
   are going to show has to be in checkbox.
5. I hope every one can understand this and stackteam please give me a
   perfect query.for this

Comment: I am not sure,In tutorsubject.php shall I give like this for($i=0; $i<count($segment); $i++){  in sql what to write }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get sub-categories same way as you fetched here categories, just loop through it.

**Try This:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tutorsubject'],$_POST['segment'])) {

    $segment = $_POST['segment'];

    foreach ($segment as $sub_cat)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sub_cat` WHERE cid = ".$sub_cat;
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            ?>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sub_segment[]" value="<?php echo $row['sid']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['sub_cat']; ?>
            </label>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: THanks I am facing one  problem here for Class I-V,Class IX-X I have show some form <select name="board" id="boardd" class="slect" required>
<option value="">---------Please select your Board--------</option>
<option value="cbse">CBSE</option>
<option value="Icse/Ise">ICSE/ISE</option>
<option value="State">STATE</option>
<option value="International">INTERNATIONAL</option>
</select> like this. like wise some other class like class XI-XII. here I am facing  class I_V is in ch_cat table this id is passing to sub_cat table. how to put if condition in foreach. where to put.that it work done.

Comment: For one record you don't need foreach, try only `$sql = "SELECT * FROM `sub_cat` WHERE cid = ".$sub_cat;` with this.

Comment: segment like btech,java,oracle,class I_V it is in child_Cat table there sub_cat  values are available in sub_cat table assume.what u implemented is correct. for class I_V we need to show some form.like this for class I_V or  class V_VIII  we need to show different forms for this how do we handle.my suggestion is again  shall i need to  write a query :$query=mysql_query("select * from child_cat c where c.cid='".$sub_cat."'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $cid=$row['cid'];
  $ch_cat=$row['ch_cat'];
} after this if($ch_Cat=='class I_V') {  show form ;} where to write this query .